# How do I set the size of query execution unit while running a Spring batch tasklet?

Tags: mysql, database, spring, spring-batch, mybatis

I'm making a Spring batch tasklet for updating a table.

My table has around 10M records. What I want to do here is to give an increment to the id of all the rows by 9M to insert old records from the other table to the very front(from id 1 to 9M).

This table is too huge to execute a query at once. I want to make the tasklet code affect on the table 1000 rows at a time.

How could I set the execution interval for a secure operation?

my query is this: UPDATE mytable set id = id + 9000000 ORDER BY id DESC;
AND using: MyBatis, Spring batch as I mentioned.

thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a tasklet instead of a chunk based approach?

Comment: @MichaelMinella thanks for your reply. it's just a simple update query so i felt that tasklet was appropriate than a series of reader, processor, and writer jobs.

Comment: @MichaelMinella Plus, after searching the solution to this for a couple of hours, I decided to use a for loop and Thread.sleep() to divide the range of records to update at a time. Still running the batch job, it seems working nicely so far

Comment: no idea why you need a `Thread.sleep()`.  Doesn't make sense to me.  If you can divide your updates into ranges, then it is absolutely appropriate to give the ranges as item, and do the update in the writer.

Comment: @AdrianShum The server having run the batch job above is currently in service to a large number of users. So, `Thread.sleep()` was necessary for a safe execution.

Comment: The approach you are using looks good, I don't think you could add any delay from spring batch side. Because entire transaction is inside db engine and there is no IO over head involved and if you introduce cursor reader or paging reader(spring batch) to add delay you would endup using lots of IO operation which would significantly degrade your db performance compared to the your approach

Comment: @KarthikPrasad Appreciate your answer! So you are saying that for a single query, the approach with a tasklet was better than creating a chunk  accompanied by a set of reader, processor and writer, since the work of I/O is costly.

Comment: Yes, since you are increment value by one, no need to read the data and copy to app server